# Common functions for codeigniter custom libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter, dry, codeigniter-3

I need to create custom libraries for my Codeigniter 3 application that have common functions used by all my custom library.

How to use function only in one place?

Comment: A small suggestion, use helper,not library for these purpose.

Answer (score 4):

What you appear to need is a helper file, not a library.
Create a file in application/helpers directory

Eg file : mycommon_helper.php
Contents as :

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function my_function($param1) {
   printf('Hello %s', $param1);
}
```

Include this in the autoload file as below

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html', .....'mycommon');  // Note _helper is omitted
```

After this you use the my_function($param1) anywhere in your code

```
 $sayIt = my_function('user2473015');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  create new custom libraries.
The library classes created by you should be placed in your application/libraries folder.

Classes should have basic prototype like this (here the name Myclass  as an example):

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Myclass {

    public function my_function()
    {
    }
}

/* End of file Myclass.php */
```

From within any of your Controller functions you can initialize your class using the standard:

$this->load->library('myclass');

$this->myclass->my_function();  // Object instances will always be lower case

Comment: That what it did.But the problem is i have function which is common to all my custom libraries. Can i use inheritance. Create a super class which have that method then my all library classes inheriting from it ?